# Attempt to de-reference a null object Error is in expression '{!testData}'

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class VfPageCount {
    public  Decimal viewCount{set;get;}
    public List<VisualPageCount__c> vf {set;get;}
    public  void testData(){
         vf= new List<VisualPageCount__c>();
        VisualPageCount__c vfp=[select id,name,Text_count__c from VisualPageCount__c];

        if(vfp != null){

            vfp.Text_count__c = vfp.Text_count__c + 1;
            viewCount =  vfp.Text_count__c;
        }
        update vfp;
    }
}
```

visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="VfPageCount" action="{!testData}">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="count on page">

        Number of times page opened : {!viewCount}

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You've asked a couple of questions now that have had issues with formatting code. The easiest way to format your code on this site is to copy and paste it into the editing window, select the code you want to format, and then push the `{}` button (or `ctrl + k` / `cmd + k`). This is especially important for things like Visualforce, which will not be rendered when people view your question (unless you format it correctly as code).

Comment: The title of your question also isn't a great place to keep the entirety of your problem statement. I, personally, tend to have a lower opinion of questions that only contain code in the question body (I think it shows a lack of effort/detail). It's also helpful if you include the entirety of the error message that you get **word-for-word** (no paraphrasing) in addition to including the stack trace (with line numbers). The error might not make much sense to you right now, but it can really help more experienced eyes to narrow down the cause of the issue. [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Few notes here. *1.* You are using a DML operation in your action method, you **should not**. *2.* If the SOQL returns more than 1 row, you will end up with an exception. That most likely seems to be the issue here.

Comment: so how to show count of my page on visualforce

Comment: To expand on Jayant's important point, using the `action` attribute exposes your application to [cross-site request forgery](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secdev_application_logic_vulnerabilities/secdev_app_logic_csrf) attacks.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
vfp.Text_count__c = vfp.Text_count__c + 1;
```

You assume the value in the database is already populated. If it is blank when you query, you will get this exception. You should instead add a null check. Typically, it would look like:

```
if (vfp.Text_Count__c == null)
{
    vfp.Text_Count__c = 1;
}
else
{
    vfp.Text_Count__c = vfp.Text_Count__c + 1;
}
```

However, it would be more efficient to use a ternary expression here:

```
vfp.Text_Count__c = (vfp.Text_Count__c == null) ? 1 : vfp.Text_Count__c + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

An exception occurs when you assign a query to a non-collection variable, and there is not exactly one row. There's no need to check if `vfp` is null, because there would be an exception before you got to this point.

Instead, you would normally want to query to a list, then check if the list is empty:

```
VisualPageCount__c[] vfp=[select id,name,Text_count__c from VisualPageCount__c];
VisualPageCount__c vpcRecord;
if(!vfp.isEmpty()) {
  // Existing record found
  vpcRecord = vfp[0];
} else {
  // We'll create a new record
  vpcRecord = new VisualPageCount__c();
}
```

At this point, Text_Count__c could still be null, so you'll also want to check for that:

```
// Check for a null value
if(vpcRecord.Text_Count__c == null) {
  vpcRecord.Text_Count__c = 0;
}
// Increase by 1;
vpcRecord.Text_Count__c++;
```

Finally, since we can now create or update a record, we'll want to switch to upsert:

```
// Save changes; upsert is insert or update
upsert vpcRecord;
```